# parse "from" address in email in javamail

Tags: parsing, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read emails from my inbox using javamail and I am specifically checking for emails that have the subject "Delivery Status Notification". Here's the code:

```
for(Message message:messages){
            for(Address a:message.getFrom()){
                if(message.getSubject().equalsIgnoreCase("Delivery Status Notification")){
                Multipart mp=(Multipart)message.getContent();                                        
                for(int i=0;i<mp.getCount();i++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                    if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/*")) {
                    String cont = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
                    System.out.println("Content: "+cont);
                    }
                }                    
                System.out.println("-----\n");
               }
            }
```

The problem is that the sender of these notifications is the "Mail Delivery System" and the line

> Address a:message.getFrom()

throws the error -- " javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string ``Mail Delivery System'' ".

How do I parse this address without having to catch the exception and then work with it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some mail servers send these delivery notification messages using a bogus and illegal From address.  You should, of course, report this bug to the mail server vendor.

While you're waiting for the vendor to fix their problem, you can work around it in JavaMail by setting the following Session property:

```
  session.setProperty("mail.mime.address.strict", "false");
```

Comment: I tried this. Still having the same problem. Is there any other way to fetch the addresses from the emails instead of using message.getFrom() in an Address array?

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  You can always use the getHeader method and try to parse the address yourself.

Comment: I am using 1.5.1 For now I am working without the addresses. I am going to try to parse using the headers and then I'll post further.

Comment: I was wrong above (and part of the JavaMail documentation is wrong), the "mail.mime.address.strict" property needs to be set as a **Session** property, not a System property.  Please try that.

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. Why don't you modify your answer so that I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

session.setProperty() was unrecognized in my case. I used below implementation and it worked!

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.mime.address.strict", "false");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
```